# Is there a way to find a function given a picture of its graph?

Tags: python, plot, graph, calculus

For example, if I have two lists,  one representing speed, and the other, time an I plot them, `plt.plot(list1,list2)`, I get a graph.

I would like to be able to get a mathematical function from that graph.

Using python or whatever else.

Comment: This question covers most of the vast field of study called "numerical science".  To be slightly more specific, google "interpolating polynomial"

Answer (score 0):

Try a polynomial regression, maybe?
Say you have the data points stored in `x` and `y` variables as an array. If you want a regression of degree 2, then:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial as P

degree = 2
coefficients = P.polyfit(x, y, degree)

x_fit = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100))
y_fit = P.polyval(x_fit, coefficients)

# get equation for regression; you can plot this using matplotlib.pyplot
# if you want to compare visually
equation = ''
for i, coefficients in enumerate(coefficients[::-1]):
    equations += f'{coefficients}x^{i} + '

# output equation
print(equation[:3])
```

It may not be exact all the time, but it'd give a base graph that you could potentially adjust to fit.